# Is default constructor optional in derived class?

Tags: c++

I am in confusion that default constructor is optional or mandatory in derived class.
Well without using default constructor in derived class I am getting the output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAbeO.png)

Comment: Post the code here instead posting a link to the image of the code.

Comment: what output you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Any class, not only derived, can either have a default ctor, or not. Even in good ol' days of C++98 it was like:

```
struct Base {
    Base(int) {}
};
struct Derived: Base {
    Derived(int x): Base(x) {}
};
```

So, `Derived d;` would not compile.

Answer (score 0):

From C++ book:

> If a base class constructor has default arguments, those arguments are
>   not inherited. Instead, the derived class gets multiple inherited
>   constructors in which each parameter with a default argument is
>   successively omitted.

When you declare any other constructor, the compiler will drop the default constructor.

First case:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
        A(){}
        A(int i){}

};

class B: public A
{
public:
        B(int i):A(i){}
};

int main()
{
        B b;
}
```

and When you compile program, compiler gives an errors :

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘B::B()’
  B b;
```

In second case:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
        A(){}
        A(int i){}

};

class B: public A
{
public:
        B(){}
        B(int i):A(i){}
};

int main()
{
        B b;
}
```

It's working fine.